# Moving data into dimension struct from database query

Tags: loops, go

I have a Join table as follows:

```
ID | CategroyID | ItemID | sizeID
 1 |          1 |      1 |      1
 2 |          1 |      1 |      2
```

I want to convert into struct as follows

```
type Category struct {
    categoryID int
    items []int
    Sizes []int
}
```

What are possible ways other than `looping`?

Comment: You can use some ORM, e.g. GORM for automating this

Comment: Could you show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I managed to move the result rows into a struct for manipulating them. But, I got stuck finding method other than looping

Comment: What's wrong about looping? One way or another, explicit or implicit, that is always going to be a loop with this schema.